# What is the difference between C# Runes and the char data type?

Tags: c#, .net, char, c#-8.0

What is the difference between Runes and the char data type in C# when it comes to handling Unicode characters?

How does using Runes impact the processing and manipulation of non-ASCII characters?

Can someone provide examples to demonstrate the distinctions and explain the benefits of utilizing Runes for Unicode character operations?

I attempted to utilize the provided code in order to discern the disparity between Runes and the char data type when it comes to processing Unicode characters.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

partial class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "Hello orld!";

        // Using char data type
        int charCount = input.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Using char:");
        Console.WriteLine("Character count: " + charCount);

        // Using Rune data type
        int runeCount = GetRuneCount(input);
        Console.WriteLine("\nUsing Rune:");
        Console.WriteLine("Character count: " + runeCount);
    }

    static int GetRuneCount(string input)
    {
        int count = 0;
        RuneEnumerator enumerator = new RuneEnumerator(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            count++;
        }

        return count;
    }
}


public class RuneEnumerator
{
    private readonly byte[] bytes;
    private int index;

    public RuneEnumerator(byte[] bytes)
    {
        this.bytes = bytes;
        index = 0;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (index >= bytes.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Rune.DecodeFromUtf8(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(bytes, index, bytes.Length - index), out _, out int bytesConsumed);
        index += bytesConsumed;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.rune?view=net-7.0). AFAIU, it only makes a difference if the input has characters that are in the surrogate range.

Comment: Just use `string.EnumerateRunes()`. Even if you loaded UTF-8 bytes into C# UTF-16 string it should be all the same. See this article https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-correctly-count-the-number-of-characters-of-a-string.htm Esp. the example block before the conclusion.

Comment: Runes will give you proper indices, like text editors show a column number. Look at Notepad++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is Microsoft official introduction article that describes the terms I am using below.

[Character encoding in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction)

Comments to your example:

Your string will result in 13 characters for the character counter and 12 characters for the Rune counter. If the word “character” here is what the user is seeing, then 12 is the expected number.

Windows use UTF-16 encoding, which means that the string is made up of 16-bit characters. Your “W” is a Supplementary code point (its hexadecimal value is 0x1D4E6 and above the 16-bit character range (up to 0xFFFF)) and therefore consists of two 16-bit characters in the string, called a "Surrogate Pair". This is what RUNE handles as one character while the “character counter” handles this as two separate characters.

As long as the string consists of characters inside the 16-bit range (up to 0xFFFF) then there are no differences between Char and Rune. But as soon as you go above the 16-bit range, there will be Surrogate pairs in the string, and Rune will handle this correctly.
What Rune is handling as one character is called a Unicode scalar value. This is a 32-bit integer value that represents all the Unicode code points except for the code points that are used for the Surrogate pairs.

It's worth noting that a “character” (from a user perspective) can also be a combination of several Unicode scalar values called “Grapheme clusters” or, in Windows, “Text elements”. These combinations of scalar values are NOT handled by Rune as one character! There are other functions in the “System.Text” namespace that handles this type of characters.

In the introduction article, below header “Grapheme clusters”, there are good comparison and examples of Char, Rune and combination of scalar values.

The following code is a simplified version as suggested in Kay Zed’s comment with additional code that shows each character (from a user perspective) and it's code point(s) and code units.

```
        public static void TestCharRune()
    { 
        string input = "Hello orld!";

        // Using char data type
        int charCount = input.Length;
        Debug.WriteLine("Using char:");
        Debug.WriteLine("Character count: " + charCount);

        // Using Rune data type
        int runeCount = input.EnumerateRunes().Count(); 
        Debug.WriteLine("\nUsing Rune:");
        Debug.WriteLine("Character count: " + runeCount);

        Debug.WriteLine("");
        int ix = 1;
        foreach (var x in input.EnumerateRunes())
        {
            char[] chars = new char[2];
            Span<char> cSpan = new Span<char>(chars,0,chars.Length);
            x.EncodeToUtf16(cSpan);
            Debug.WriteLine($"\nIx: {ix++}: {x} Code point: 0x{x.Value.ToString("x4").ToUpper()} (UTF-16: length: {x.Utf16SequenceLength} and code unit(s): 0x{((int)chars[0]).ToString("x4").ToUpper()}{(((int)chars[1]) != 0 ? " + 0x" + ((int)chars[1]).ToString("X4").ToUpper() : "")})");
        }
    }
```

### This results in following output:

Using char:
Character count: 13

Using Rune:
Character count: 12

Ix: 1: H Code point: 0x0048 (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x0048)

Ix: 2: e Code point: 0x0065 (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x0065)

Ix: 3: l Code point: 0x006C (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x006C)

Ix: 4: l Code point: 0x006C (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x006C)

Ix: 5: o Code point: 0x006F (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x006F)

Ix: 6:   Code point: 0x0020 (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x0020)

Ix: 7:  Code point: 0x1D4E6 (UTF-16: length: 2 and code unit(s): 0xD835 + 0xDCE6)

Ix: 8: o Code point: 0x006F (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x006F)

Ix: 9: r Code point: 0x0072 (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x0072)

Ix: 10: l Code point: 0x006C (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x006C)

Ix: 11: d Code point: 0x0064 (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x0064)

Ix: 12: ! Code point: 0x0021 (UTF-16: length: 1 and code unit(s): 0x0021)

Answer (score -1):

Runes are 32-bit whereas Char is 16-bit.
See: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23578